# Stop character when hitting platform

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a little problem with a game I'm making. You see, I want to stop my character moving through the platforms I have placed, but since my characters instance is places in another class than my characters class, I cannot acces its velocity variables and so on. Im quite frankly not sure how I should solve this.

Here is the character class.

```
     package  com.classes
    {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.display.Stage;
        import com.senocular.utils.KeyO

bject;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Gubbe extends MovieClip
    {


        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var key:KeyObject;


        private var speed:Number = 0.6;
        private var vx:Number = 0;
        private var vy:Number = 0;
        private var gravity:Number = .4;
        private var maxspeed:Number = 21;
        private var maxspeedG:Number = 50
        private var friction:Number = .92;
        private var nospeed = 0;
        private var fall:Boolean = false;
        private var platt:platform;

        public function Gubbe(stageRef:Stage) : void {


            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            key = new KeyObject(stageRef);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);



        }

        public function loop(e:Event) : void
        {
            //Knapptryck
            vy += gravity;
            y += vy;
            x += vx;


            if (key.isDown(Keyboard.LEFT))
                vx -= speed;
            else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT))
                vx += speed;
            else
                vx *= friction;

            if (key.isDown(Keyboard.UP))
                vy -= speed;
            else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.DOWN))
                vy += speed;
            else


            //Positions updatering
            x += vx;
            y += vy;

            if(vx > 0)
                fall=true;
            if(vy > 0)
                fall=true;




            if (vx > maxspeed)
                    vx = maxspeed;
            else if (vx < -maxspeed)
                    vx = -maxspeed;

            if (vy > maxspeed)
                    vy = maxspeed;
            else if (vy < -maxspeed)
                    vy = -maxspeed;



            if (x > stageRef.stageWidth)
            {
                    x = stageRef.stageWidth;
                    vx = -vx;
            }
            else if(x < 0)
            {       
                    x = 0;
                    vx = -vx;
            }
            if (y > stageRef.stageHeight)
            {       
                    y = stageRef.stageHeight;               
                    vy = (-vy*.4);
            }
            else if (y < 0)
            {
                    y = 0;
                    vy = -vy;
            }



        }





    }

}
```

And here is the Engine class, where the character and platform instances are located.

```
package  com.classes{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event; 
import com.classes.Gubbe;

public class Engine extends MovieClip
{
    public var ourGubbe:Gubbe;


    public function Engine() : void
    {
        ourGubbe = new Gubbe(stage);            
        ourGubbe.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        ourGubbe.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        stage.addChild(ourGubbe);


        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, land);

    }

    public function land(e:Event) : void
    {

        if(ourGubbe.hitTestObject(platform))
        {

        }
    }


}
```

}

Im thinking hitTestObject, but I dont know how to make the character instance stop when colliding with the walls. I'll be gratefull for any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

You just need add some public booleans to your character like:

```
public var leftfree:Boolean = true;
public var rightfree:Boolean = true;
```

Then you need to add 2 different hittest checks for left and right sides of your character in your engine class like:

```
if(ourGubbe.hitTestObject(platform))
{
   if(platform.x > ourGubbe.x) ourGubbe.rightfree = false;
   else ourGubbe.leftfree = false,
}
else
{
   ourGubbe.leftfree = true;
   ourGubbe.rightfree = true;
}
```

Then you can use that booleans in your character class to "move it left or right 1 pixel(depends on your character movement speed, use actual movement speed instead of 1 pixel) in every frame related to collision side to keep it from entering to the platform.

Comment: Thanks! I edited it but the character doesn't stop and rather just start twitching like hell and I cant move it at all. I did the boolean false if("boolean name"==false) vx = -vx. But it just twitches out of controll and doesn't bounce back.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice using Getters and Setters. That way you can reach variables from other classes.

In Gubbe you would add:

```
public function getXVelocity():Number
{
    return vx;
}

public function setXVelocity(value:Number):void
{
    //Check if value is within the set limits.
    if (value > maxspeed)
        value = maxspeed;
    else if (value < -maxspeed)
        value = -maxspeed

    vx = value;
}

public function getYVelocity():Number
{
    return vy;
}

public function setYVelocity(value:Number):void
{
    //Check if value is within the set limits.
    if (value > maxspeed)
        value = maxspeed;
    else if (value < -maxspeed)
        value = -maxspeed

    vy = value;
}
```

As you can see you can build in some security in the setters just like I did now with maxspeed.

Then in Engine you can do stuff like this:

```
if (ourGubbe.hitTestObject(platform))
{
    //Get the current velocity.
    var ySpeed:Number = ourGubbe.getYVelocity();

    //Move Gubbe back so it is outside the platform again.
    ourGubbe.y -= ySpeed;

    //Set the y velocity to 0.
    ourGubbe.setYVelocity(0);
}
```

The collision handling only serves as example. Don't do your collision handling with only the above or your character will show some weird behaviour.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks alot! Im not that great with as, but I did what you suggested in the engine class, plus the xspeed ofcourse, and it works when Im coming from underneath but when landing on it I simply slide slowly through it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Like I said, the collision handling serves only as an example, I didn't think about what operations exactly to use.
if you change the ourGrubbe.y -= ySpeed into ourGubbe.y += ySpeed then it should work. Keep in mind that the Y gets bigger when something moves from up to down in 2D space.